# Who will feel more pain when jumping from a height, a tall man or a short man?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, estimation, free-fall

Whether the impact on a tall man is greater than a short man when he jumps from a height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you jump from a height, you gather momentum. Absorbing this momentum at landing reduces the size of the maximum force, and thus the "pain".

Let us assume that the distance over which a person can absorb the momentum of the fall is proportional to their height (proportional to the length of their legs).

In that case, the taller person can absorb the momentum over a greater distance; put differently, if they apply a constant force with their leg as it is bending, then the energy of the fall ($mgh = E$) is absorbed over a longer distance $y$. In that case, the force needed for a person of the same mass is smaller if they have longer legs (are taller).

But if you say that a person's mass is proportional to the square of their height (following the BMI model) or even the cube (following the "spherical cow" assumption), then the energy will increase with height faster than the length of the legs.

In other words - "it depends" on the assumptions you make.